# Search for empty fields on a table

Tags: asp.net, mysql, gridview

I tried the command below. It's a `DataSource` of a `GridView` and it's written on my `.aspx` page, so I can not use characters like `""` or `''`. This code does not return me anything.  I also tried to pass (string.empty, "" and null) as parameters in the `codebehind`.  Nothing worked and I don't know what else to do...

```
SelectCommand="SELECT ch.id, sit.descricao as situacao, resp.responsavel, ch.dt_cadastro, ch.previsao_termino, func.descricao as funcionalidade, 
                                  proj.descricao as projeto ,pr.id as prid, pr.prioridade, clb.clube
                                  FROM chamados AS ch  
                                  INNER JOIN prioridades as pr  ON ch.prioridade = pr.id
                                  INNER JOIN clubes as clb ON ch.clube = clb.id 
                                  INNER JOIN responsaveis as resp ON ch.responsavel = resp.id
                                  INNER JOIN situacoes as sit ON ch.situacao = sit.id 
                                  INNER JOIN projetos as proj ON ch.projeto = proj.id
                                  INNER JOIN funcionalidades as func ON ch.funcionalidade = func.id WHERE ch.responsavel IS NULL"
```

`Obs:`the field I want to filter as `null` they are `int32` fields.
( I know that `int32` can't be `null`) But I just didn't know what to do, so I tried everything that came to mind.

Comment: did you try `IFNULL()` in mysql?

Comment: No, how does that work ? It would be like this ?
`WHERE ch.responsavel IFNULL()` ?

Comment: I think `ch.responsavel IS NULL` is correct if you have to use it in where clause IFNULL() is used in SELECT clause

Comment: refer this : http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/problems-with-null.html

Comment: @BhavikShah I did ! I was thinking... I have an `INNER JOIN` with the field that I want to check if it's `null`. I guess that's why it is not working , what you think ? Because if it's `null`, the inner join wont retrieve anything... Am I right ?

Comment: Yes that might be the problem try removing it

Comment: @BhavikShah cant I make it return the source to the GridView even if its null ? I'd like to retrieve Everything, even if it's null or not. But the `INNER JOIN` doesnt return anything... ;s

Answer (score 0):

This query will always return no results because you use `INNER JOIN` in this statement:

```
INNER JOIN responsaveis as resp ON ch.responsavel = resp.id
```

and use the `WHERE` statenent where you compare one of `INNER JOIN` fileds with `NULL`

```
WHERE ch.responsavel IS NULL
```

The `INNER JOIN` joins **ONLY** fields which are NOT NULL. So these two statement except each other.

Comment: Yeah i Know... I commented with `BhavikShah`... Thanks valex !!

Answer (score 0):

I found out the problem, it was:

I'm using `INNER JOINS` and as @valex told me:

`The INNER JOIN joins ONLY fields which are NOT NULL. So these two statement except each other.`

The solution was change the `INNER JOIN` for `LEFT JOIN` and worked like a charm !

Thanks everyone !